# cannot use internet through ethernet in12.04 getting error net connection has .local domain. Works fine in wifi but problem using wired connection

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

I am using ubuntu 12.04. Earlier I was using net through ethernet port & it was working fine. But I now get a error that the service provider has a .local domain and the net connection shuts down.
When I spoke to the service provider he says the mac no is binded & I will have to use a wifi connection to use internet in ubuntu.

I am faced with a dilemma whether to move back to windows as if i cannot use internet in ubuntu the updates will not be possible.

Is there any other solution to this ? Plz help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me while investigating a similar problem.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126

Especially the following:

```
 lspci -nn | grep 0200

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar -xf compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```